# Windows Mobile C++ Tray Icon

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-mobile

I'm trying to place my application that is mainly running in the background in a 'tray-like' area on the Windows Mobile 6.5.

I do it the obvious way by with Shell_NotifyIcon

```
BOOL ShowTrayIcon(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE hIns, BOOL bShowIcon)
{
BOOL bRet = FALSE;

g_structNotifyIconData.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
g_structNotifyIconData.hIcon = LoadIcon(hIns, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_GPSCOMPASS));
g_structNotifyIconData.hWnd = hWnd;
g_structNotifyIconData.uCallbackMessage = WM_SYSTRAY_MSG;
g_structNotifyIconData.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON;
g_structNotifyIconData.szTip[0] = 'Bzz';
g_structNotifyIconData.uID = ID_TRAY;

if (bShowIcon)
bRet = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &g_structNotifyIconData);
else
bRet = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &g_structNotifyIconData);


return bRet;
}
```

This is where i am trying to place the icon :

[Tray icon within the 'today' area http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/666d99dc.jpg](http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/666d99dc.jpg)

The **Shell_NotifyIcon** does the thing but the Icon is not shown on the Today screen, i can see it's in the tray from any place **except** the Today/Home screen.

Now I've read somewhere that this is because the Tray area in Today screen is reserved for system notifications and 'we' can't place any icons in there - well if that's true, can somebody please confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, Shell_NotifyIcon doesn't support adding the icon in the Today screen. This is even one of the first things mentioned in the function documentation:

*This function sends a message to the system to add, modify, or delete an application-specific icon from the taskbar status area. It does not affect icons appearing on the home screen.*

You can try using [SHNotificationAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930981.aspx).